# Content switch in drag and drop using HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have drag and drop code where i need to switch content in drag and drop. Currently when you drop a tr on another tr it append this new tr but I want these two tr should change their position instead of append it. I am not interested in any plugin and also if it can be done using jquery it would be gr8. 
HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="tblrw1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Some Dummy Text1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  id="tblrw2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Some Dummy Text2        
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  id="tblrw3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Some Dummy Text3        
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td  id="tblrw4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            Some Dummy Text4        
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
//alert("Id "+ev.target.id+" Being drag");
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

CSS:

```
td
{
    width:500px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding:8px;
    cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: Can you please setup a JSFiddle...

Comment: I tried that but in JSFiddle getting error dragstart event not defined so I thought directly to put code here. anyway here is a path for JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/ZSNJ5/

Answer (score 0):

you can change the drop function
use classes for tr in the table say class="trDrop"

```
function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var obj=document.getElementById(data);
var dropPosX=ev.ClientX;
var dropPosY=ev.ClientY;
$("table").find('.trDrop').each(function(){
var tableTr=$(this);
var posX=tableTr.offset().left;
var posY=tableTr.offset().top;
var width=posX+tableTr.width;
var height=posY+tableTr.height;
// Now the main trick
if(dragPosX>posX && dragPosX<width && dragPosY>posY && dragPosY<height)
{
obj.InsertAfter(tableTr);
}
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vishal,I have just added my trDrop in your function but its not working

Comment: $("table").find('')trDrop.each(function(){
this line needs to be edited
$("table").find('trDrop').each(function(){

Comment: $("table").find(ev.target.id).each(function(){